# Asp.Net pagination best practice

Tags: asp.net, pagination

I'm using linq to sql to get my data, when I set the page size on my data grid and the user selects page 2, I get a postback and I re-read all the data to show the second page. I suspect there should be a better way of doing this, a way that ends up reading just the data I need to show. I was wondering if there are any code samples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *really* ease the database load, take a look at [client-side paging](http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/use_jquery_and_aspnet_ajax_to_build_a_client_side_repeater.php)...

Comment: This really depends on the data.  Google couldn't get away with client-side paging on a search that returns a million pages.  (Although, it sounds like he's loading the entire set from the DB either way)

Comment: Of course. Removing load from the DB will increase the load on other parts of the project - naturally; the job has to be done somewhere. Cliend-side paging will increase network traffic _once_, and reduce DB load by _a lot_ - but you always have to think about _how much_ the network load is increased, and decide if it's worth it.

Answer (score 3):

You should really be looking at the [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) methods.

See ScottGu's post on [LINQ to SQL (Part 3)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx), and search the page for "Paging our Query Results" - this has some nice examples.

Alternatively, if you use the [LinqDataSource control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.aspx), and you're talking to a SQL 2005 or 2008 database, you should get this behaviour automatically. [LINQ to SQL (Part 5)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx) covers that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<new_log> Search(dbDataContext db, int _user,int _pageNumber, int _rowCountPerPage)
{
var query = (
                   from p in db.new_log
                  where p.created_by == (_user < 0 ? p.created_by : _user)  orderby p.id descending
                  select p 
                  )

              .Skip(_pageNumber * _rowCountPerPage).Take(_rowCountPerPage); 
return query;

}
```

Key Points:

1.we have to disable the viewsate in page or control level to improve the performance.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableViewState="false" %> OR <asp:GridView
   EnableViewState="false" runat="server"  />
```

2.Try to write single query to get result.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1779601/5120205.aspx/1?p=True&t=634814907594742030