# ASP.NET MVC Paginated List Example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I do pagination in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc)
>   [Paging search results with asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663616/paging-search-results-with-asp-net-mvc)

Can anyone point me towards a canonical ASP.NET MVC paginated list example?

Comment: It's been asked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446196/how-do-i-do-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254332/paging-in-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432387/willpaginate-for-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677905/asp-net-mvc-search-form-with-pagination http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770691/issues-with-pagination-in-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663616/paging-search-results-with-asp-net-mvc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890855/asp-net-pagination-best-practice

Comment: recently i found with cool controls, tooltip, first, next, last, previous check this [mvc 4 paging nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/MVC4.Paging/), [demo web page](http://mvcpaging.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the famous nerddinner tutorial: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm